# Single yml file to NLP pipeline using Spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pipeline, spacy

I am working on an NLP project using Spacy V3. The goal is to cluster a sort of text in categories. Can I use only spacy V3 pipelines to perform it? Using spacy to preprocess the texts and vectorize and then classify using scikit learn KNN, but only in a single yml file.

Update: I have created different scripts to perform each step (preprocess, vectorize and classify) but the data are not being shared among them and I need a project structure where I can simply run the train step or the whole workflow (from preprocess to classification and maybe create a package). Can I use Spacy and an yml file for that?

Comment: What have you tried ? Why are you refering to a yml file ?

Comment: @ygorg Spacy V3 has a new end-to-end approach using yml file [see more](https://spacy.io/usage/projects) to project workflow.